# Angular Ivy without zones: what is the most convenient way to trigger change detection?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-ivy

I would like to get rid of the zones in my app. I am considering several options for triggering change detection:

1. Manual triggering change detection by invoking `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` / `ΘmarkDirty(this)` in a component on every update of a property used in a template. Something like this:

```js
// extra side effect for observables:
readonly todos$ = this.todosService.getTodos().pipe(
  tap(() => this.cdr.detectChanges()), // or `ΘmarkDirty(this)`
);

// or local state
toggle() {
  this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // or `ΘmarkDirty(this)`
}
```

```html
<div [class.open]="isOpen">
  <!-- AsyncPipe will invoke `ChangeDetectorRef#markForChanges()` which does nothing without zones -->
  {{ todos$ | async | json }}
</div>
```

2. `PushPipe` like [this](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-microapp/blob/master/projects/client-a/src/app/push.pipe.ts). This pipe is very similar to built-in `AsyncPipe` but instead of `ChangeDetectorRef#markForChanges` it invokes `ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges`. Taking in mind the upcoming release of Ivy I should be prepared to call `ΘmarkDirty(this)` where `this` is a reference to the component instance. I can get a reference to the component instance via injected `ViewRef`'s `context` property but this property is private and it's a bad idea to rely on a private API. **Is there any official way to get a component instance reference in a pipe used in this component's template?**
3. `ReactiveComponent` like [this](https://youtu.be/rz-rcaGXhGk?t=1336). This approach enforces the inheritance of some basic functionality from a parent class. I expect people to override `ngOnDestroy$` in a child class and forget to call `super.ngOnDestroy$()`. **We can't enforce a proper override of lifecycle hook methods, right?**
4. `@observed` decorator like [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/quantum-angular-maximizing-performance-by-removing-zone-e0eefe85b8d8). This approach heavily relies on `Θ`-prefixed functions and properties which are subject to a potential change. **Also, it feels a little bit hacky so it is too risky to use in production, right?**

**Which approach do you prefer? Am I missing better options?**

Comment: I’m not sure why you would want this - but I’d wait a year or so to give the Angular team a chance to make these interfaces public (which will happen eventually).. It’s a bit too early to go zone-less I think.

Comment: Bear in mind that detectChanges does the rendering immediately. Thus a single response from server would cause re-render everywhere where the data is used. When using zone and markForCheck the change detection is only run once after the zone execution completes.

Comment: @MikeOne I'm just exploring this opportunity to go zone-less. Let's see...

Comment: @kvetis Yes, I'm aware of this synchronous nature of `detectChanges`. But my app does not have a lot of state updates. Mostly I care about initial rendering and a bundle size. I am considering this opportunity to sacrifice runtime performance with `detectChanges` a bit in favour of better initialisation speed. Moreover, Ivy's `markDirty` will behave in a similar way to `markForCheck`.

Comment: At this point I'm not even sure what to suggest...